# How come some urls work and some don't?

Tags: internet, dns, internet-connection

I had some problems with my router, so I switched to a new one (a linksys WNR612v3, though that probably isn't the problem).

Now some pages work, and some pages don't examples of non-working pages are google.com and facebook.com

What might cause this and how can I debug it? I tried several browsers. The error i get is
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: More details about the connectivity and the symptoms are necessary. You need to use some networking tools to debug that, but that also depends on your operating system.

Comment: Can you run `ipconfig /all` and dump the results in pastebin, and link that to us?

Comment: Have you enabled advertisement blocking in the router? Try a reset-to-default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those web sites redirect you to a secure (HTTPS) connection (SSL over port 443).  Seems you have some blockage (firewall or proxy problems) related to that.